# I keep getting these special character symbols: ������

Tags: php, database, utf-8, character-encoding, special-characters

I keep getting these special character symbols: Bel�n. This information comes from my database.

I have already added `<meta charset="utf-8">` everywhere, but they don't seem to change.

I am guessing this error comes with the database connection. Here is my data base connection code, but I do not know where to add the charset or how.

```php
namespace App\Classes\Model;
use PDO;
use PDOException;

class Database
{
    public $databaseHandler;
    public $host = "localhost";
    public $dbname = "database";
    public $user = "root";
    public $password = "";

    public function __construct()
    {
        try {
            $this->databaseHandler = new PDO("mysql:host=$this->host;dbname=$this->dbname", $this->user, $this->password);
            //echo "Database Connected";
        }
        catch(PDOException $error){
            echo $error->getMessage();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how you set a charset (utf8 or whatever you need)

```
$this->databaseHandler = new PDO("mysql:host=$this->host;dbname=$this->dbname;charset=utf8", $this->user, $this->password);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can also add the following line

```
$this->databaseHandler->exec("set names utf8");
```